# How to add folders directly as buttons automatically?

Tags: php, json, hyperlink

I have a few folders like `a`, `b` etc each containing an index.html. At the root, I have a main page (index.html). I want the folders `a`, `b` etc to display as links on my main page such that when it's clicked, people are sent to the corresponding index.html. I also want to make sure that each time a new folder, say `c` is added it displays as a link to my homepage.
How do I go about it?

Comment: Are you serving your website? If so, what's the backend language? Is it Node.JS? You only added JavaScript in your tags and I don't think you'll be able to do that in the frontend alone. Why do you need this? It doesn't sound very safe.

Comment: It's just for a project I am going to use locally with Apache (XAMPP)

Comment: Since you're using XAMPP, I posted a solution based on PHP. Can you please update your question so that the reader may know you are using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### With PHP

#### FILE: `index.php`

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
        var dirList = JSON.parse(`<?=
            json_encode( glob('*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) );
        ?>`);

        document.write('<ul>');

        for (let dir of dirList) {
            document.write(`
                <li>
                    <a href=${dir}>Link to directory ${dir}</a>
                </li>
            `);
        }

        document.write('</ul>');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

You probably already know this, but your project's directory (containing both your `index.php` and the folders you want listed) should be stored under `xampp/htdocs` for it to work.

**Note:** Sorry for using `document.write()`, but it was faster to write and easier to read than calling `document.createElement()` and appending things lots of times.

#### Explanation

To pass the data from PHP to JS, I formatted it as JSON:

1. Use [`glob()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to retrieve an array of dirs;
2. Encode the array as JSON;
3. Echo it (the `<?=` + `?>` block is a short for `<?php echo` + `?>`);
4. Receive it in JavaScript, parse the JSON array and store it in var `dirList`;
5. Iterate through elements of the array and create the links inside a list.

How you handle or style it is actually up to you. You can send the HTML code with the entire list already assembled from PHP if you want, but I'm leaving most of the job to JavaScript.